# Two definition of element of null space for symmetric bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming $B$ is a symmetic bilinear form over a vector $\mathcal V$, about the null space of $B$, I found two different definition:

(1) $v\in \mathcal V$ is the element of null space, if $B(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in \mathcal V$.

(2) $v\in \mathcal V$ is the element of null space, if $B(v,v)=0$.

I want to know whether the two definition are same ?  In fact, I feel they are different. If so, I want to know whether the dimension of the two null spaces by different definition are same ?

Comment: Please work through an example given by $B(v,w) = v^T \begin{bmatrix}1& 0 \\ 0 &-1\end{bmatrix} w$ for $v, w \in \mathbb R^2$